# Xcode 6.1 SDK update for Yosemite Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) crash

Tags: ios

I updated Xcode and fixed all the errors that it brought on in my code, when I run the simulator it crashes with the  Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode=0x0) error, I deleted outlets that were not being used, any ideas? Or do I have to wait for an update that will fix it?

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is crashing.  Xcode? The simulator?  Your app?  (If it's your app, please add a symbolicated stack trace of the crash to your question.)

Comment: the simulator is crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting more, I was able to resolved these conflicts by using the @objc marker in my swift files in all swift methods that could get called by my Obj-C code, including init methods. For example, change override init(frame: CGRect) to @objc override init(frame: CGRect).

As an aside: I'm still a bit confused by why the @objc flag wasn't 'required' (although it may have been best practice) in Xcode 6.0 but suddenly was a requirement in Xcode 6.1.

From:
[[Fatal trap exceptions in Obj-C / Swift project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26498919/fatal-trap-exceptions-in-obj-c-swift-project][1])